# Actions-On-Google Card Subtitle not displaying in Simulator or Android phone

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using the DialogFlow Fulfillment Inline Editor to build a quick prototype/POC Google Action.  I'm trying to add a subtitle to a Card using the Node.js code below (based on the default Fulfillment Node.js code) and it's not showing up in the Simulator or on my Android phone.  Otherwise, the Card is rendering properly - all other properties are being displayed, but no subtitle.  I've also tried creating the Card separately and setting the subtitle property directly (card.subtitle = 'The Subtitle';), but that also did not work.  There is no 'subtitle' being returned in the response data, and there are no errors being logged (either in the "ERRORS" tab or the "View logs").

```
  agent.add(new Card({
    imageUrl: 'https://example.org/images/logo.png]',
    title: `${titleCase(theTitle)}`,
    subtitle: 'The Subtitle',
    text: `${theText}`,
    buttonText: 'Get More Information',
    buttonUrl: 'https://example.org/info'
  }));
```

Thoughts on what might be going on here?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `subtitle` for a Card to my knowledge. You are probable confounding with the BasicCard from the Actions On Google library which does have a `subtitle` property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the [Dialogflow fulfillment code itself](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/src/rich-responses/card-response.js#L250), there's no subtitle field being set when the platform is Actions on Google.

Comment: Is that the expected behaviour though? From what I can see, there is a subtitle property in this file: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/response/card/basic.ts

Comment: Hmm... according to [Dialogflow basic card vs card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004493/dialogflow-basic-card-vs-card), Card does have a subtitle.

Comment: I don't know if this is intentional, but it does explain the behavior.

Comment: @NickFelker - This would explain it.  Seems like a bug.